# Webpage does not refresh in production until hard refresh

Tags: javascript, python, webpack, browser-cache

For my website, I have a flask server serving a file generated by webpack. Unfortunately, when I update the file, the webpage often does not update until a hard refresh (Ctrl-F5), due to browser caching. I want the webpage to update after a regular refresh, as most users do not know about hard refresh. In development, there are ways of getting around hard refresh, such as webpack-dev-server. What is the easiest way of doing this in production?

I have the following `webpack.config.js` file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['react-hot-loader/patch', './js/main.js'],
    output: {
        filename: "./static/bundle.js",
    },
    resolveLoader: {
    moduleExtensions: ['-loader']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loaders: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'css-loader',
                query: {
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

The Flask server is serving an `index.html` file that looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bust the cache yourself. Webpack has the provision for it.

```
output: {
    filename: "./static/bundle-[hash:6].js",
},
```

The bundled file generated would look like: `bundle-1e3dab.js`

Now, in `HTML`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle-1e3dab.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now every time you build, if something gets changed, the hash will be updated.

> **NOTE:** Don't forget to update the file path in HTML each time you build or customize your build to have a replace task which automatically updates the HTML file. You can use [Webpack Manifest Plugin](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin) for this.

**UPDATE**

Change `entry` in your webpack file:

```
// Entry, files to be bundled separately
  entry: {
    'main': [
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
       './js/main.js'
    ]
  },
```

And for updating the hash

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var basePath = path.join(__dirname, '/');

function replace (statsData, fileName, readFilePath, regex, assetChunkName, writeFilePath, replaceWith) {

  // Read the data so that hash can be read
  let stats = statsData.toJson();

  if (!stats.errors.length) {
    // read the file i.e. index.html and store the contents
    let contents = fs.readFileSync(path.join(readFilePath, fileName), 'utf8'),
      // Replace the pattern with the user-defined replacedWith variable or the chunkHash webpack provides
      htmlOutput = contents.replace(
        regex,
        replaceWith || stats.assetsByChunkName[assetChunkName][0]
      );

    // Write back the modified contents into the file
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(writeFilePath, fileName), htmlOutput);
  }
}
```

inside the configuration, after `module` key, add the following code:

```
plugins: [
  function() {
    // To be executed when build is done
    this.plugin('done', (statsData) => {
      // `statsData` has the info regarding the file bundling(hash)

      // Replace the filename with the update chunkHash for build/prod only
      replace(
        statsData,
        'index.html', // filename which needs to be modified
        path.join(basePath, '/dist/'), // path from where to read index.html
        /bundle\.js/i, // regex i.e. which needs to be replaced
        'bundle',
        path.join(basePath, '/dist/')) // path from where to write index.html, can be same if needs ot override
    })
  }
]
```

Replace the pathname and you're done :)

let me know if you face any errors.

Comment: Hi softvar, that was one of the things I tried. I couldn't figure out a way to read the JSON file generated by manifest plugin into the index.html file though, nor could I find an example online for that. Do you know of or have an example for that? Thanks.

Comment: Have updated the code with exact code you need to update the bundle.js in your index.html file

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question about webpack, a server has no way to force browser don't use cache. What you can do is adding some postfix to your url like replacing `bundle.js` with `bundle.js<it's md5>`. In this case, as the url is different, browser will treat it as a new resource.